# Display product on checkout/cart when empty

Tags: cart, products

I would like to display products on `site.com/checkout/cart` when there are **no items in the cart** because a lot or visitors click the cart button without having a product in there.

The current code of the `noItem.phtml` looks like this:

```
<div class="page-title">
    <h1><?php echo $this->__('Shopping Cart is Empty') ?></h1>
</div>
<div class="cart-empty">
    <?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->toHtml() ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('checkout_cart_empty_widget'); ?>
    <p><?php echo $this->__('You have no items in your shopping cart.') ?></p>
    <p><?php echo $this->__('Click <a href="%s">here</a> to continue shopping.', $this->getContinueShoppingUrl()) ?></p>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('shopping.cart.table.after'); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to achieve what I wanted and it was pretty easy.

From the admin panel I created a cms/block called noitem_products and pasted the following code which displays products marked as popular on the homepage:

```
{{block type='catalog/product_list' category_id='44' grid_column_count='3' hide_toolbar='1' products_count='4' template='catalog/product/list.phtml'}
```

In order to display the products from this block I use the following code in noItems.phtml to call the block:

```
<p><?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('noitem_products')->toHtml(); ?> </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a new template file somewhere in your design folder, and edit the `checkout.xml` in your layout folder with the following code:

In the layout handle: `checkout_cart_index` and in the reference `<reference name="content">` add another block:

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="core/template" name="shopping.cart.table.after" template"path/to/your/template"/>
</referece>
```

Now you can add your own html to show products

Comment: But I don't need to show products on the checkout page, just on the cart page when there is no product added. Magento handles a noItem.phtml file in case there are no products added to cart.